# Improvements in uploading of files, vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I want to upload file to git without saving on local disk. I use vaadin + java in my webapp, and upload component from vaadin.

```
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String MIMEType)
{
    this.filename = filename;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        // exist any possibility to no saving file in filepath (only push
        // to git)
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                filepath + File.separator + filename));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // How to omit it, I don't want to save file in filepath...
        return null;
    }

    return fos;
}

public void uploadSucceeded(Upload.SucceededEvent event)
{               
    try {
        // this method read file from filepath. Exist any possibilty to
        // transfer file from upload panel to here without saving this
        // file in filepath ?
        commitToGit(filepath + File.separator + filename);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // removing file from filepath, it is no comfortable for me
        File file = new File(filepath + File.separator + filename);
        if (file != null) {
            file.delete();
        }      
    }  
}
```

Comment: your commitToGit method must just provide a InputStream, you can the pipe the OutputStream of the uploadcomponent to the InputStream of the git uploader.

Comment: Could you provide example of code... ? I don't have any idea how it reach...

Answer (score 0):

Look here for the pipe functionality

[Best way to Pipe InputStream to OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715979/best-way-to-pipe-inputstream-to-outputstream)

in the receiveUpload method you setup the pipe between the uploading file and your git connector.
The uploadSucceeded method is then not needed or can be used to cleanup resources.

Comment: hmm...Probably I need conversio inn other side. I have (fos) FileOutpuTStream, the first method in method commitToGit() looks: private byte[] readStreamToByteArray(InputStream stream) - so I need inputStrea, not OutputStream...