# How to read the pdf content from response and write it to another new pdf file

Tags: java, httpresponse, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream, ioutils

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 9 0 R
/Outlines 8 0 R
/Names 6 0 R
```

i am trying to read above pdf content response from rest end point in java class and trying to write it to another file
but the file is getting corrupted and I could not view the pdf generated

```
File file = new File("Data.pdf");-- trying to write data to this
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)
\\service call to download pdf document
out.write(response.getBody().getBytes());
```

how to write the pdf content to another file or generate new pdf in a proper way?

Comment: What are you using for your ReST Implementation? Can you give us more code? What class is the `response`? Apache Commons HttpClient? Jax-rs? HttpUrlConnection?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to read from an `InputStream` and then write to an `OutputStream`. This question has been answered several times e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715979/best-way-to-pipe-inputstream-to-outputstream) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574837/connecting-an-input-stream-to-an-outputstream) and there are lots of possible solutions. Since you also tagged ioutils one possible way is to:

```
File file = new File("Data.pdf");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)
IOUtils.copy(response.getBody(), out);
```

This presumes that `response.getBody` returns an `InputStream`. If you supply more code we can tell for sure. (This depends on your restclient implementation you are using like JAX-RS, Spring-Rest, Apache httpClient or HttpUrlConnection...

Answer (score -1):

PdfReader class in iText 7 has got an overloaded version that takes InputStream as an argument. Using this method, you can basically read the bytes of your first input pdf using ByteArrayInputStream. iText 7 has got a PDFWriter class that can write to an OutputStream too. Please refer to the following snippet. PdfDocument class then can read the input  pdf file and write it to a new file using pdfWriter.

```
    //Pdf bytes returned by some rest API or method
    byte[] bytes = {};
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    
    //File where you want to write the pdf and update some content
    File file = new File("Data.pdf");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    
    PdfDocument dd = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(bin), new PdfWriter(out));
```

Comment: The question was not about a PDF library but about basic file reading / writing